# Read backwards the content of a file saved into an StringList

Tags: delphi

I can read a File loading it into an StringList, but after that I want to reverse its content, copying it backwards to a second StringList. I need help filling backwards this second StringList.

```
procedure TForm1.btnsteClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
   Lista01, Lista02 : TStringList;
   i, NumeroLinhas:Integer;
   UltimaLinha :string;
begin

   // Create the temporary StringList
   Lista01 := TStringList.Create;
   Lista02 := TStringList.Create;

   // Load the content of the input file
   Lista01.LoadFromFile('C:\entrada.txt');

  try
     // Loop through the StringList
     for i:=0 to Lista01.Count -1 do
      begin
        // Show the content of the line
        //ShowMessage('linha ' + IntToStr(i) + ' é ' + Lista01[i]);
        Lista01[i] := Lista01[i];
       end;

       // Retrieve the number of lines
       NumeroLinhas := Lista01.Count;
       // Retrieve last line
       UltimaLinha  := Lista01[NumeroLinhas -1];

     for i:=0 to Lista01.Count -1 do
      begin
        // I want to copy backwards Lista01 into List02
        // Lista02[i] := "";

      end;

        // Save on file the modifications
        Lista01.SaveToFile('C:\saida1.txt');
        Lista02.SaveToFile('C:\saida2.txt');

       finally
         // Release memory
       FreeAndNil(Lista01);
       FreeAndNil(Lista02);
       ShowMessage('Sic');
   end;

end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will do what you are looking for, to fill Lista02 with the content of Lista01 in reverse order.

```
for i := Lista01.Count - 1 downto 0 do begin
  Lista02.Add(Lista01[i]);
end;
```

Comment: @WarrenP , Not a homework, I'm just having trouble in code, be more humble

Comment: It is really sad you answered a question that is so unclear and has no use to future readers here. You've made it so the poster has no reason to come back and improve it by posting your answer. Shame.

Comment: If the Portugese version is clear, the user should have posted it on the Portugese Stack Overflow. It is not crystal clear to those who do not speak or read Portugese. This is an English language site, and the question needs to be clear to the English language users who come here in the future.

Comment: Okay, if you can rewrite the question for a counting down loop, or "reverse a list using a reverse order list" or whatever, it could be fine.